# Read excel files in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am new to Cypress. How to read data from excel files using Cypress? Searched in google but could not find useful answers.

Answer (score 4):

In cypress you can create [cypress task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Examples) to read **xlsx** file with  [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs) library.

## Usage

cypress\integration\read-xlsx.spec.js

```
context('Xlsx file', () => {
  it('Read excel file', () => {
    cy.task('readXlsx', { file: 'my-excel.xlsx', sheet: "Sheet1" }).then((rows) => {
      expect(rows.length).to.equal(543)
      // expect(rows[0]["column name"]).to.equal(11060)
    })
  })
})
```

### Need to install xlsx

```
 $ npm install xlsx
```

### Create read excel fuction

cypress\plugins\read-xlsx.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

const read = ({file, sheet}) => {
   const buf = fs.readFileSync(file);
   const workbook = XLSX.read(buf, { type: 'buffer' });
   const rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet]);
   return rows
}

module.exports = {
   read,
}
```

### Use function as Cypress task (plugin)

cypress\plugins\index.js

```
const readXlsx = require('./read-xlsx')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    'readXlsx': readXlsx.read
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an instruction how to use excel as source for cypress tests https://medium.com/@you54f/dynamically-generate-data-in-cypress-from-csv-xlsx-7805961eff55

First you need to conver your xlsx file to json with Xlsx

> ```js
> import { writeFileSync } from "fs";
> import * as XLSX from "xlsx";
> try {
>   const workBook = XLSX.readFile("./testData/testData.xlsx");
>   const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workBook.Sheets.testData);
>   writeFileSync(
>     "./cypress/fixtures/testData.json",
>     JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4),
>     "utf-8"
>   );
> } catch (e) {
>   throw Error(e);
> }
> ```

Then import json file and loop over each row and use the data in the way you want. In this example it tries to log in to a system.

> ```js
> import { login } from "../support/pageObjects/login.page";
> const testData = require("../fixtures/testData.json");
> describe("Dynamically Generated Tests", () => {
>   testData.forEach((testDataRow: any) => {
>     const data = {
>       username: testDataRow.username,
>       password: testDataRow.password
>     };
>     context(`Generating a test for ${data.username}`, () => {
>       it("should fail to login for the specified details", () => {
>         login.visit();
>         login.username.type(data.username);
>         login.password.type(`${data.password}{enter}`);
>         login.errorMsg.contains("Your username is invalid!");
>         login.logOutButton.should("not.exist");
>       });
>     });
>   });
> });
> ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26190662)

Comment: @ArdentCoder added essential parts to answer

Comment: I tried this but I face this issue : _fs.readFileSync is not a function. How can I solve that ?

Comment: where I have to put a try-catch block?

Comment: @CharlesR install using "xlsx": "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.20.0/xlsx-0.20.0.tgz"

Answer (score 0):

For me the first answer pretty much worked. But i had to make a small fix.

**Use function as Cypress task (plugin)**

cypress/plugins/index.js

```
const readXlsx = require('./read-xlsx')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    'readXlsx': readXlsx.read
  })
}
```

when i used this code i got the below error in cypress.

*CypressError
cy.task('log') failed with the following error:
The task 'log' was not handled in the plugins file. The following tasks are registered: readXlsx*

and the below fix worked

```
const readXlsx = require('./read-xlsx')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    'readXlsx': readXlsx.read,
    log (message) {
      console.log(message)
      return null
    }
  })
}
```