# Handle Excel file with Cypress: "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL

Tags: cypress

I have followed the instructions of [https://blog.knoldus.com/reading-data-from-excel-file-cypress/][1]

... and some other suggestions.

But I have not getting anywhere close to read/"change to json" an Excel file.

The error looks like this in cypress/support/cy-commands.ts:134:44:

```
cy.task('parseXlsx') failed with the following error:

> The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of ObjectLearn more
```

and

```
> 134 | Cypress.Commands.add('parseXlsx', () => cy.task('parseXlsx', { filePath: InputFile }));
```

The cy-commands looks like this:

```
import { InputFile } from './spa/Component-API';
Cypress.Commands.add('parseXlsx', () => cy.task('parseXlsx', { filePath: InputFile }));
```

In the Component-API InputFile is defined as string.

Tn the plugin/index.js file

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as xlsx from 'node-xlsx';
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    parseXlsx(filePath) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const jsonData = xlsx.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
          resolve(jsonData);
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      });
    },
  });
```

And the test itself (not finished):

```
validateExcelFileNotEmpty() {
    cy.get('@LASTDOWNLOADEDFILE').then((name) => {
      const fileName = name as unknown as string;
      cy.log(`Validating excel file: ${fileName}`);
      cy.parseXlsx(name as unknown as string).then((jsonData) => {
        const rowLength = Cypress.$(jsonData[0].dataset).length;
      });
    });
  }
```

Basically all what is described in the link above. I have written other task and they are working, but not this one!

Answer (score 2):

`{ filePath: InputFile }` is defining an object with a `filePath` field.
But your `parseXlsx` function is expecting to receive just a plain string.
So the correct way to call the `parseXlsx` **task** is the following:
`Cypress.Commands.add('parseXlsx', () => cy.task('parseXlsx', InputFile ));`

Besides that, I don't understand why you try to pass an argument to you custom command whereas it accepts none.

Comment: Sorry, either "Cypress.Commands.add('parseXlsx', () => cy.task('parseXlsx', InputFile ));" nor what I defined before in cy-commands works for this. Additionally, in the propsed case: eslint complains "'InputFile' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts" and if I let it run the same error as above.

Comment: where do you want to get the file path value from? should it be a custom command parameter? or imported from some other source file?

Comment: Thanks for your answers: all I would like to do is to check if an excel file is not an empty excel file, but has rows/columns filled with values. The file and its path comes from  an alias(ed) field (see LASTDOWNLOADEDFILE above). From what I understand, I defined my task `parseXlsx(filePath) {` , so that I can hand in the parameter filepath. thx again.

Comment: Actually the following solution works. Without parsing etc: [stackoverflow.-61934443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934443/read-excel-files-in-cypress) _italic_