# How to read data from excel in cypress

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I need to read some datas (example name, place etc..) from a excel sheet, How can I do this, I am new to cypress, How can I read data, anyone please show me a small example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read excel files in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934443/read-excel-files-in-cypress)

Answer (score -1):

please try nodejs module for this operation,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file