# reading data from multiple tabs in excel

Tags: cypress

I have some data in multiple tabs in excel and those need to be read using cypress. Is there a way to do it? The only suggested way to read data from excel is to convert to JSON file. So, I referred and wrote this in ./cypress/support/command.js file with an intention that each tab will be stored as JSON file.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('dataFile', (excelFile) => {
    let XLSX = require('xlsx');
    let fs = require('fs');
    let XLBook = XLSX.readFile('cypress/fixtures/' + excelFile);
    let XLTabs = XLBook.SheetName;
    for(let i = 0; i < XLTabs.length; i++)
    {
        let XLTabName = XLTabs[i].toString();
        let XLData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(XLBook.Sheets[XLTabs[i]);
        fs.writeFile('./cypress/fixtures/jSONData.json', JSON.stringify(XLData , null, 2), (e: string) => {
            if(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I used the below command in my test to use it.

```
cy.dataFile('File1.xlsx');
```

But, the test was highlighting this error:
Property 'dataFile' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Types for custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Types-for-custom-commands) to resolve the error

> ***Property 'dataFile' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'.ts(2339)***

But you cannot use a custom command, because both `let XLSX = require('xlsx')` and `let fs = require('fs')` must be used in a task.

Please see this answer [Read excel files in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66321431/16997707) for the broad strokes.