# How to validate content of xlsx and xls files in cypress

Tags: cypress, xlsx

I have below scenario:
I’m using cypress with feature file. The feature file scenarios are like this
Using cucumber preprocessor

Feature: Validate transaction numbers in Excel files

Scenario1: Validate transaction numbers in 'xlsx' file
Given user clicks on the download button
Then report file download to the cypress download folder
And the transaction number should exist in the "abcd.xlsx" file

Scenario2: Validate transaction numbers in 'xls' file
Given user clicks on the download button
Then report file download to the cypress download folder
And the transaction number should exist in the "abcd.xls" file

I need help validating transaction numbers in both xlsx and xls file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add to your question the test you have tried so far. Stackoverflow is not the place to ask for general tutorials. Please include details of the files, where is transaction located.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is given here [Read excel files in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934443/read-excel-files-in-cypress), but that answer is a bit out of date.

It uses Cypress v9 syntax, so I'll update to the latest syntax.

Install the package [SheetJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx).

[image]

```js
yarn add -D xlsx
```

In **cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const fs = require('fs')
const xlsx= require('xlsx')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        readXl({file, sheet}) {
          const buf = fs.readFileSync(file);
          const workbook = xlsx.read(buf, {type:'buffer'})
          const rows = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet])
          return rows
        },
      })
    },
  },
})
```

In **test.cy.js**

```js
context('xlsx file', () => {
  it('Read excel file', () => {
    cy.task('readXlsx', { file: 'my-excel.xlsx', sheet: "Sheet1" })
      .then((rows) => {
        expect(rows.length).to.equal(543)
      })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file names are `abcd.xlsx` and `1234.xls`, and you don't need to verify contents, but only that the files are downloaded, you can take one of two approaches [(taken from this website)](https://www.programsbuzz.com/article/cypress-verify-file-download):

You can use `cy.readFile()`, which has an implicit check that a file exists prior to reading the file, meaning if the file has not been downloaded, the test will fail.

```js
// code to trigger the download
cy.readFile('cypress/downloads/abcd.xlsx');
cy.readFile('cypress/downloads/abcd.xlsx', { timeout: 25000 } ); // if file is large to avoid failing while file is downloading
```

Or, [you can use the `cy-verify-downloads` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cy-verify-downloads), which operates in a similar way.

```js
cy.verifyDownload('abcd.xlsx');
```

If you need to validate something of the contents of the file, you can use `readFile()` to yield the contents of the file for validation.

```js
cy.readFile('cypress/downloads/abcd.xlsx')
  .then((contents) => {
  // code to validate contents
});
```